# upload a project to Google App Engine created using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I created an **'App Engine'** project (with **Maven**) using this link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven
Now i am not sure how should i deploy this. Whenever I open my application in eclipse and click on **"Deploy to  App Engine"**, I get an error saying **"[application] is not an App Engine project"**. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Since you're using Maven, why not using it to deploy to App Engine? Simply run `mvn appengine:update`.

Comment: thanks, using this command now i am able to deploy project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured the appengine maven plugin in your pom, and specified your appid and version in your appengine-web.xml, then you can simply run this command at the command prompt:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

This will run mvn package, then deploy to the appid in your appengine-web.xml. From memory, the first time it will also open a browser window for you to login to your google account.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your application you can use a

[appengine-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/)

the update goal allows you to make a deploy.

Comment: all the build plugins mentioned in the link are already a part of my POM. What should i do next?